# How can i expand a default tree view

Tags: treeview

i have try many things

javascript code

<div class="tree_main" style="margin-top: 20px">

<ul class="main_ul">

<li>

<span class="plus"> </span>

<input type="checkbox" id="c_bs_1" />

<span>1. Base</span>

<ul id="bf_l_1" class="sub_ul" style="display: none">

<li>

<span class="plus"> </span>

<input type="checkbox" id="c_bs_11" />

<span>1.1. Tabelas</span>

<ul id="bf_l_11" class="sub_ul" style="display: none">

<li>

<span class="plus"> </span>

<input type="checkbox" id="c_bs_111" />

<span>1.1.1. Entidades</span>

<ul id="bf_l_111" style="display: none" class="inner_ul">

<li>

<span class="plus"> </span>

<input type="checkbox" id="c_bs_1111" />

<span>1.1.1.1. Fornecedores</span>

<ul id="bf_l_1111" style="display: none" class="inner_ul">

<li><input name="permissao" value=" inserir" type="checkbox" id="c_io_1111C" /><span> Inserir </span></li>

<li><input name="permissao" value=" listar" type="checkbox" id="c_io_1111R" /><span> Listar </span></li>

<li><input name="permissao" value=" alterar" type="checkbox" id="c_io_1111U" /><span> Alterar </span></li>

<li><input name="permissao" value=" apagar" type="checkbox" id="c_io_1111D" /><span> Apagar </span></li>

......

```
<style>
    .footer {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #outer {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .inner {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .plus, .minus {
        display: inline-block;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 16px 16px !important;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        /*vertical-align: middle;*/
    }

    .plus {
        background-image: url(https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/plus.png);
    }

    .minus {
        background-image: url(https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/minus.png);
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    }

    ul.inner_ul li:before {
            content: "├";
            font-size: 18px;
            margin-left: -11px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            float: left;
            width: 8px;
            color: #41424e;
    }

    ul.inner_ul li:last-child:before {
            content: "└";
        }

    .inner_ul {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 35px;
    }


</style>
```

<script type="text/javascript">

```
$(".plus").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("minus").siblings("ul").toggle();
        });

        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
            $(this).siblings("ul").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
        });

        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
            $(this).siblings("ul").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
        })

        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
            var sp_msg = $(this).attr("id");
            var sp = document.getElementById($(this).attr("id"));
            if (sp.checked) {
                let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="permissao"]:checked');
                let values = [];
                checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
                    values.push(checkbox.value);
                });
                var ListaPermissoes = values;
                $('#strObs').val(ListaPermissoes);
                utilizador = $('#strUtilizador').val()
                var DescPermissao = 'O utilizador ' + utilizador + ' pode aceder a: ' + $('#strObs').val();
                $('#strObs').val(DescPermissao);
            }
            else {
                let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="permissao"]:checked');
                let values = [];
                checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
                    values.push(checkbox.value);
                });
                var ListaPermissoes = values;
                $('#strObs').val(ListaPermissoes);
                utilizador=$('#strUtilizador').val()
                var DescPermissao = 'O utilizador ' + utilizador + ' pode aceder a: ' + $('#strObs').val();
                $('#strObs').val(DescPermissao);
            }
            if (sp_msg.substring(0, 4) === "c_io") {
                var ff = $(this).parents("ul[id^=bf_l]").attr("id");
                if ($('#' + ff + ' > li input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == $('#' + ff + ' > li input[type=checkbox]').length) {
                    $('#' + ff).siblings("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);
                    check_fst_lvl(ff);
                }
                else {
                    $('#' + ff).siblings("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
                    check_fst_lvl(ff);
                }
            }
            if (sp_msg.substring(0, 4) === "c_bf") {
                var ss = $(this).parents("ul[id^=bs_l]").attr("id");
                if ($('#' + ss + ' > li input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == $('#' + ss + ' > li input[type=checkbox]').length) {
                    $('#' + ss).siblings("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);
                    check_fst_lvl(ss);
                }
                else {
                    $('#' + ss).siblings("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
                    check_fst_lvl(ss);
                }
            }
        });
```

</script>